# Traveling to United states with ESTA, even though I have valid visa

Tags: visas, usa, esta, israeli-citizens

I can't seem to find my previous passport with a valid B1/B2 visa.
Because I can't find it and I have an upcoming trip, I made the ESTA form and it was approved.
My question is whether I can enter only with the ESTA permit (while I have a valid visa somewhere)
Any experience with it?

Thanks

Comment: Will you have a passport?

Comment: Have you reported the loss of your previous passport to the authorities? I'd suggest doing it, to be ultra safe.

Comment: I assume the visa is in an expired passport, and you have a current valid passport from a VWP eligible country?

Comment: It depends on your nationality...

Comment: If the visa was on an expired passport, it is not a problem. Some countries by default just keep the expired passport. OTOH why did you have a B1/B2 visa if you can have an ESTA? (remember that conditions may be different).

Comment: OP should certainly add their nationality, as it matters. I can guess Israeli by the name, and because Israel recently became VWP eligible.

Comment: Thanks everyone, Yes I am Israeli.
I did the normal B1/B2 Visa few years ago when the ESTA was not possible.
I have a new valid passport because the previous (with the B1/B2 visa) is expired.
I haven't reported the passport is lost because I am not living in the last few months in Israel and I need to go to the police for that...

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem entering the US under the Visa Waiver Program (aka ESTA) in this situation.

Presuming that you are actually considering your previous/expired passport lost, you should [report this](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/lost-stolen-visas.html) to the US Consulate in your country of residence - not so much because the passport has been lost, but because the visa has been.

Whether or not you need to report the passport as lost to the Israeli government will depend on the country - many countries do not require this for an expired passport, however as the visa is still current (even if in an expired passport) it needs to be reported lost to the US government.